# Add Metadata to XeTeX PDF's

Tags: xetex, pdf, metadata

Is it possible to specify the metadata in PDF's made with XeTeX?

Here's an example of the type of metadata I'd like to set (and a speculative form for XeTeX):

```
\pdfinfo
{ /Title (My Masterpiece)
  /Author (YourName)
  /CreationDate (D:YYYYMMDDhhmmss) % this is the format used by pdf for date/time
  /Subject (...)
  /Keywords (...)
}
```

While it's clearly possible to [do precisely this with pdfTeX](http://www.wlug.org.nz/PdfLatexNotes), the following link suggests it's not possible with XeTeX:
[pdfauthor, pdftitle etc. in XeTeX](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/tMRBZhbtwsQrtsY1hST9).

I'd be grateful for thoughts and feedback.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The link you gave has an answer, which is to use hyperref package:

```
\usepackage[pdfauthor={Your Name},
            pdftitle={The Title},
            pdfsubject={The Subject},
            pdfkeywords={Some Keywords},
            pdfproducer={XeLateX with hyperref},
            pdfcreator={Xelatex}]{hyperref}
```

Works with XeLaTeX anyway.

(One of those links you gave is *very old*: it is now possible to use \hypersetup too.)

Comment: though you can't change the `pdfproducer` tag with hyperref

Comment: You should be also able to set these values using `\hypersetup{..}` in the same way. This has the benefit that they don't get passed through LaTeX package option routine which can cause trouble with complex values.