# Enable PDF commenting with TexShop

Tags: pdf, texshop, comments, drm

I'm using TexShop (Mac OS 10.5) to typeset a manuscript and I would like to share the generated PDF with some colleagues. In the process, I would like to add some comments to the generated PDF and allow my colleagues to do the same. The freely available Acrobat Reader has commenting functionality, but apparently the PDF must explicitly allow commenting (and probably other forms of editing as well). Is there a way that I can tell TexShop and/or the underlying Tex distribution to typeset the PDF with the proper permissions?

As an alternative, I just discovered the `todonotes` package, with which pop-up comments can be added to the source code and created when the document is originally typeset. This will work for me and perhaps one other colleague, but it's unlikely that I will be able to get all of my colleagues to pull the tex source from my git repo and edit it...so my original question remains.

Comment: I don't know that PDFs can be editable with a property setting (I thought that required Acrobat Pro, or some other editing s/w like Preview on Mac). If you find the property name you should be able to set it based on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23235/eliminate-edit-pdf-properties-added-by-pdflatex

Comment: There is a question like this which I can't find, but I remember one solution was to use crocodoc (www.crocodoc.com). It allows users to make comments on pdf and work collaboratively.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not if the PDF has to be editable with Adobe Reader (there are free readers that allow this, though - e.g. [Foxit Reader](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Foxit_Reader)). Adobe Reader only allows this if the PDF has been created by Adobe products; the PDFs have to be digitally signed with a key by Adobe. See the [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Adobe_LiveCycle_Reader_Extensions) and [a detailed explanation](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/313613).